# How to size clusters on a map using js

Tags: javascript, clustering, mapbox-gl-js, elasticsearch

I have clusters containing population counts in a mapbox-gl map. The cluster data is based on geohash aggregations from elasticsearch. I am having trouble sizing the diameter of my clusters. They should be based on the population count within the cluster as well as zoom level. What is the recommended algorithm for sizing clusters?

Here is what I have...

```
circleWidth = 10 * Math.log10(docCount + 1) * this.zoomLevel + "px";
```

where docCount is the number of people in the cluster and this.zoom level ranges from 0 to 18 where 0 displays the entire world and 18 shows just one or 2 city blocks.